# How to create a UI in Shiny from a for loop whose length is based on numeric input?

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

As an extension of this example:

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html

Say you would like the for loop to be of a length determined by a numeric input. So for example, extending the linked example (using just the second part of it):

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Creating a UI from a dynamic loop length',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Determine Length of Loop
      numericInput(inputId = "NumLoop", "Number of Loops", value = 5, min = 1, max = 5, step = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # UI output
      lapply(1:input.NumLoop, function(i) {
        uiOutput(paste0('b', i))
      })
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  reactive({
    lapply(1:input$NumLoop, function(i) {
      output[[paste0('b', i)]] <- renderUI({
        strong(paste0('Hi, this is output B#', i))
      })
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As far as I can tell there are two problems with the code:

In the UI, I don't know how to legitimately use the input from `NumLoop` in the for loop of the UI output. I have experimented with the `conditionalPanel` function with no luck.

In the server, once I put the loop behind a `reactive` function to make use of `input$NumLoop` I no longer have access to those `renderUI` outputs in the UI.

Any ideas of how to solves these issues would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, as per @Dean, yes the second `renderUI` shouldn't be there

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Creating a UI from a dynamic loop length',
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Determine Length of Loop
      numericInput(inputId = "NumLoop", "Number of Loops", value = 5, min = 1, max = 10, step = 1)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      # UI output
      uiOutput('moreControls')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:input$NumLoop, function(i) {
      strong(paste0('Hi, this is output B#', i),br())
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Works great, love having the demo too!

Comment: The `output[[paste0('b', i)]] <- renderUI({` line is unnecessary and incorrect. All you need inside the lapply is `strong(paste0('Hi, this is output B#', i))` (or you can wrap it in a `div()` if you want to make sure each one if put on a new line)